# SKPaymentTransactionObserver sees many updatedTransactions at startup

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I've got an app that offers IAP of auto-renewing subscriptions.

When the app starts, the following method is called, sometimes many times, and I'm not sure by who or why.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions;
```

What creates or updates these transactions?

I get the sense that it should be called when a recurring subscription renews. If several renewal periods have passed, is it called for each? For example, Yearly products should renew Hourly in the sandbox. So if I wait several hours to relaunch the app, should I get one for every hour I was offline?

Another odd thing: it's been a few days since the original purchase of the yearly product. Shouldn't the product stop renewing after 6 cycles or so? Is there any way to manually stop that renewal?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It might be because you don't finish a transaction after it is completed. I'm not sure if it's applicable to auto-renewing subscriptions, but I experienced that problem with non-consumable one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this happens because you have bought Auto Renew Subscriptions, and now they are renewed.

Comment: Yes. I do think this was the purchase renewing (sometimes multiple times), and I've come to write off the never-ending renewal as iTunes Sandbox Inconsistencies.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The only reason I could think of is that your old transaction didn't finish properly.
Wait for few hours and try again. It could be a sandbox issue as well.